# Formula field not showing value between 2 related object

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have 2 objects

1. Contracts - Custom
2. Sales Submission (Opportunity Process) - Custom

They are related because of Lookup relationship.

GOAL: I want to show in Sales Submission Object that when the Contract Status is Cancelled, the string "Cancelled" should populate in this formula field. This is my formula:

Formula in Sales Submission:

```
IF ( Ispickval ( Related_Contract_Record__r.Contract_Status__c, 'Cancelled'), 'Cancelled' ,


'NotCancelled')
```

Expected Result: String "Cancelled" if Contract Status is Cancelled else "NotCancelled"
Result: 'NotCancelled' even though the Contract Status is Cancelled.

I also created a Checkbox

Formula:

```
IF ( ISPICKVAL ( Related_Contract_Record__r.Contract_Status__c , 'Cancelled' ), TRUE , FALSE )
```

Result: False, even if Contract Record is Cancelled

Comment: Regarding the formula field in your first example: It seems that your condition is checking if Contract_Status__c is equal to Active and not equal to "Cancelled" as your description mentioned

Comment: Aw sorry, I did some changes before I posted my question. I'll edit my first formula

Comment: I'm just curious if a text formula field of Related_Contract_Record__r.Contract_Status__c isn't enough? Assuming that a String like "Cancelled" or "Not Cancelled" is enough

Comment: I agree, but the formula does not return “Cancelled” string eventough the Contract Status is set to Cancelled....Im not sure why, I have the same formula for other objects but its working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this instead:

```
IF ( TEXT( Related_Contract_Record__r.Contract_Status__c ) == "Cancelled", 
'Cancelled',
'NotCancelled')
```

and for your checkbox:

```
IF ( TEXT( Related_Contract_Record__r.Contract_Status__c ) == 'Cancelled' ), 
    TRUE,
    FALSE )
```

You should see that your formula will then evaluate accordingly. The only time there would be any issue outside of this is if there is no access to the related record, or is not populated. Inaccessible objects would cause this to return false, all the same as if it was not there.